# Azure Blob Storage StartCopy with source pointing to Cloud Convert

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, internal-server-error

I have Cloud Convert converting videos, and when it completes, I tell Azure **BLOB** Storage to download the file from it's the conversion output URL, using the method `CloudBlockBlob.StartCopyAsync`.

I must say, this used to work. I haven't changed a single line of code until this process started to fail.

Now, anytime Azure tries to download from Cloud Convert, it fails with the message `500 InternalServerError "Copy failed."`. If I copy the download the URL in the browser, it downloads the file normally. The process works with the Storage Emulator.

My question is, is anyone else having the same problem? How do I fix this? Do I need to download the file and upload it to Azure Blob Storage myself?

Comment: Can you trace the request/response through a tool like Fiddler? May be share a URL that we can try?

Comment: @GauravMantri The Azure Storage is a service. I don't have access to the server. I could do it with the emulator, but the emulator works. I can send you an URL of the file I'm trying to download, but it appears that any output URL from cloud convert would have the same result.

Comment: Can you send me the URL? I will try to simulate the same.

Comment: @GauravMantri https://host123d1qj.cloudconvert.com/download/~-Msb2haregAwHIVvoqFW_101v3c   It also works with HTTP

Comment: I was able to perform the copy operation successfully however I noticed the file size of the blob is 0 bytes. Upon further inspection I found that the link you shared has `Content-Disposition` property set. Can you try by removing the `Content-Disposition` property value on the source file?

Comment: @GauravMantri the call to CloudBlockBlob.StartCopyAsync runs OK. But once I check the CopyState it says it failed with the message I said in the question. I don't think I can remove the header from the file. It's hosted by Cloud Convert and generated automatically after a conversion. I only have read access to it.

Comment: I believe what's happening is that when you initiate the copy, Azure Blob Storage Service issues a `GET` request on the movie file. However because the content disposition property is set, the request results in downloading the file on the blob storage service servers. My guess is that this is not an allowed operation thus you're getting a 500 error from service.

Comment: @GauravMantri I don't think it's that. It wouldn't be very smart from Azure to take into consideration the Content-Disposition header, specially if it can't do anything with it. If it was me, I would just ignore it. And I think the Http Status 500 is from Cloud Convert's URL, not Azure's. Azure's method I called simply starts a asynchronous copy operation. The error was discovered when I checked the CopyState. Anyway I contacted support from both companies and I'll see if this works

Answer (score 0):

> But once I check the CopyState it says it failed with the message InternalServerError "Copy failed."

During testing on my side, I didn't encounter this error. Please try to debug your code and capture the detailed error to see whether this error is thrown in your code or the server-side.

> I must say, this used to work. I haven't changed a single line of code until this process started to fail.

According to your description, I registered an account in Cloud Convert and converted a .pdf file to .docx file. Then I tested it on my side and got the same result as Gaurav said that the blob could be created successfully however the size of the blob is 0 bytes. I assumed that Cloud Convert might make some adjustments. Since you could download the file in the browser, then you could follow the code below to achieve your purpose as an alternative approach.

```html
//pdf-to-docx.docx
url = "https://host123d1qm.cloudconvert.com/download/~7-9EyBedLQQyCoh41ONW6h1RpFY";
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{   
    //download the file via the URL provided by CloudConvert
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    //define the block blob object
    string filename = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim(new char[] { '"' });
    string contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
    blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
    //upload blob
    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I'm using the endpoint to start an asynchronous copy of the file. I call the StartCopy method in the SDK and it returns (or can return) as soon as the request is received by azure, but before the copy completes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894037.aspx). I also have converted a video, but I don't think the type of the file changes anything. Now, in the .NET SDK, there's a property in the blob called `CopyState` that indicates me the status of the copy. The message I got was from there. If there's better message somewhere, I don't know it.

Comment: I could make it work as in your example. I have done so in another project that don't use Azure. But since I use azure, I want the storage to download the file for me. I don't want the video to go through my server if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the Azure Storage Data Movement Library: [Git Docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement). Specifically, see TransferManager.CopyAsync(). Another thing to look into is changing the access type on the destination container.